# Android retrofit mapper 3.x is not supported

Tags: java, android, post, postman, retrofit

i use post request as raw json (in postman there is no problem in the url)
my problem is the call api is sucessful 200 but it send empty data. i have noticed that mapped 3.x is not supported when i call the api for post)
(i read that retrofit use Gson automatically so i had to change that to json)
i have raw json request body and the response is empty
Code:

public interface PostRequest {
@Headers( "Content-Type: application/json" )

```
@POST("maximo/oslc/os/PFEAF_SRADD/")

Call<ResponseBody> CreateData(@Header("MAXAUTH") String user, @Body RequestService service);
```

}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RequestService service;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
```

String code="mycode";
RequestService post = new RequestService("Moyen","description crée par ahmed depuis android studio","F.AHMED","601995","F.AHMED");
Call userList = ApiClient3.getUserServicepost().CreateData(code,post);

```
    userList.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("failure",t.getLocalizedMessage());

        }
    });
}
```

}

here is what i call the api what i have :

```
Connected to process 30490 on device 'samsung-sm_a750f-320032cd4f84c5db'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
    Installing application
    VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
D/PhoneWindow: forceLight changed to true [] from com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.updateForceLightNavigationBar:4238 com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.updateColorViews:1510 com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.dispatchWindowAttributesChanged:3216 android.view.Window.setFlags:1148 com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout:2444 
I/MultiWindowDecorSupport: updateCaptionType >> DecorView@bcff28f[], isFloating: false, isApplication: true, hasWindowDecorCaption: false, hasWindowControllerCallback: true
D/MultiWindowDecorSupport: setCaptionType = 0, DecorView = DecorView@bcff28f[]
W/e.gestion_acti: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/e.gestion_acti: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/e.gestion_acti: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/e.gestion_acti: Accessing hidden field Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->theUnsafe:Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->allocateInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> POST http://192.168.111.10/maximo/oslc/os/PFEAF_SRADD/
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 176
    MAXAUTH: mycode
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"affectedperson":"F.AHMED","assetnum":"601995","description":"description crée par ahmed depuis android studio","reportedby":"F.AHMED","reportedpriority_description":"Moyen"}
    --> END POST (176-byte body)
D/ViewRootImpl@7e0882b[MainActivity]: setView = com.android.internal.policy.DecorView@bcff28f TM=true MM=false
D/ViewRootImpl@7e0882b[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2220) new=(0,0,1080,2220) req=(1080,2220)0 dur=10 res=0x7 s={true 527939842048} ch=true
D/OpenGLRenderer: createReliableSurface : 0x7aeba9c980, 0x7aebaab000
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
                          **W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported**
I/gralloc: Arm Module v1.0
D/ViewRootImpl@7e0882b[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@bcff28f[MainActivity]
    getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@bcff28f[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=com.example.gestion_actif ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/ViewRootImpl@7e0882b[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=(0,0,1080,2220) ci=(0,63,0,126) vi=(0,63,0,126) or=1
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@bcff28f[MainActivity]
    getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=com.example.gestion_actif ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 201 Created http://192.168.111.10/maximo/oslc/os/PFEAF_SRADD/ (371ms)
    Date: Sun, 30 May 2021 22:06:35 GMT
    X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1
    X-Content-Type-Option: nosniff
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    X-XSS-Protection: 1
    Location: http://192.168.111.10:80/maximo/oslc/os/pfeaf_sradd/_RFMvMTIzNQ--
    Content-Length: 0
    Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000_4f9ylC2YyrMfsnQryFKkNL:-1; Path=/; HttpOnly
    Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
    Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2"
    Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Language: en-US
    <-- END HTTP (0-byte body)
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@bcff28f[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=com.example.gestion_actif ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=68
D/ViewRootImpl@7e0882b[MainActivity]: stopped(true) old=false
D/ViewRootImpl@7e0882b[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@bcff28f[MainActivity]
    getNavigationBarColor() -855310
E/ViewRootImpl@7e0882b[MainActivity]: Surface is not valid.
```